# New integer array shifted to the right?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I should input the array `x[ ]` and create the new array `y[ ]`, that is shifted to the right from the original.

I'm havong trouble with the first element, `y[0]`

- for ex. if i input    `{7, 8, 4, 2, 3}`
- the code below returns: `{-693726240, 7, 8, 4, 2}`

where is the error?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m=0, x[100],y[100];
    cin >>n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter "<< i+1 <<". element: ";
        cin >> x[i];

        if (i>0) 
            y[m++] = x[i-1];
        else     //THIS IS FOR Y[0] BUT DOESN'T WORK
            y[m++] = x[n-1];  
    }
    // ARRAY SHIFTED TO THE RIGHT:
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        cout << y[j]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Have you look at [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)?

Answer (score 3):

Loop starts with `i == 0`. You read the i-th element at i-th iteration. `i == n - 1` is yet some time in the future when you read `x[n - 1]` in the 0-th iteration. C++ is not obliged to initialise variables for you to any particular value, so when you read from a not-yet-initialised location, you are likely to get garbage (in this case, `-693726240`).

To solve this, you have to solve the time paradox. Don't assign anything at iteration 0; wait till the loop is done and all data is in, and only then sneak back and fill in the 0-th element.

Alternately, read the entirety of `x` first, then when you know all the values, use your current algorithm to shift `x` into `y` (i.e. separate the current do-everything loop into a read loop and shift loop). This way, all the `x` values will be known when you start on `y`, and you won't have any time-travel mishaps.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are looking for a circular shift given that you wrote `y[m++] = x[n-1]`

Amadan's answer highlights a way of solving your problem, here is some code you can follow :

```
for(int i = 0;i < n-1;i++){
 cin>>x[i];`
 y[i+1] = x[i];
}
cin>>x[n-1];
y[0] = x[n-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

got it, great, @Amadan thanks for explanation and quick answer

I also removed "j" and "m" as separate variables for the new array, 
think it's not needed actually, I can use the same "i" and "n" that are used for the original array  (right? Or should I keep the new variables?)

Here's corrected code that works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m=0, x[100],y[100];
       cin >>n;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter "<< i+1 <<". element: ";
        cin >> x[i];

            if (i>0) 
                y[i] = x[i-1];
    }

    y[0] = x[n-1];
    // ARRAY SHIFTED TO THE RIGHT:
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    cout << y[i]<<" ";
    }
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

also I tried the other alternative @Amadan suggested, and used it also for left shifting
- first input all the elements, then assigning another array elements when they're all known

I consider this as the best one, tested and working. Thanks again:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, n, x[100],y[100], z[100];
       cin >>n;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    cin >> x[i];

    // ARRAY SHIFTED TO THE RIGHT:
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    if (i > 0)  y[i] = x[i-1];
    else        y[i] = x[n-1]; 
    cout << y[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // ARRAY SHIFTED TO THE LEFT:
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    if (i < n-1)    z[i] = x[i+1];
    else        z[i] = x[0]; 
    cout << z[i]<<" ";
    }
return 0;

}
```